# What remotes are available for the Canon EOS 60D?

Tags: remote, triggers, canon-60d

I've found it really difficult to pinpoint exactly what remotes are compatible with the Canon EOS 60D.

The camera specifications say, "N3 type wired remote control" (which doesn't mean a lot to me).

[Canon's AU website](http://canon.com.au/en-AU/For-You/Digital-Cameras/EOS-Digital-SLR-Cameras/60D) has no remote accessories listed for the camera, and the [TC80N3 remote](http://www.canon.com.au/en-au/For-You/Accessories/DSLR-Camera-Accessories/Remote%20Control/TC80N3) (which I *think* might work) doesn't have the 60D listed as a compatible camera.

Can anyone give me any pointers as to which remotes are compatible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

'N3' refers to the connector type for the remotes... It is a proprietary Canon standard, and Canon remotes which are compatible with the 60D have 'N3' in their model numbers, specifically:

- Canon Remote Switch (RS-80N3)
- Timer Remote Controller (TC-80N3)

There are also several companies that make N3 compatible wired remotes, including offerings from Adidt, Nova Photography, and Seculine. Generally speaking these tend to be cheaper (sometimes significantly so) but as you might imagine, quality can range from excellent to abysmal, so look for reviews before buying off-brand.

Comment: www.dealextreme.com and eBay have lots of cheap, aftermarket N3 compatible triggers for the fraction of the Canon OEM price. For what a remote essentially is, I'd get the aftermarket one twice before shelling the money for an OEM remote.

Comment: BTW, the Rebel series has a standard 2.5mm stereo connector instead of the N3. This makes it possible to easily build a DIY remote from cheap available parts.

Comment: Ah, but the TC-80N3 is a great remote, it is way more than just a shutter release. Love mine for those situations which need it.

Comment: Using an N3 remote with a camera that has an E3 port, including the 60D, requires an [adapter cable](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/1165080-REG/canon_1157c001_ra_e3_remote_controller_adapter.html).

Answer (score 3):

The Canon 60D which I own, purchased in USA, has a 2.5mm remote connector just as EOS Rebel models have, not the N3 type connector in the high-end Canon models.

Comment: I can confirm that the 60D does have a 2.5mm connector, not the N3-type. Should be possible to find this information in the manual.

Answer (score 1):

Take any micro headphone plug strip the wires on one end and touch them together to take a photo!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your needs you probably could get away with a super cheap IR remote and Magic Lantern.  Magic lantern will let you do stuff from timelapses to dual-iso/hdr shots and more.  Search google for magic lantern, go to the main site and read about it to decide if it's for you.